# Lost 12 hours of progress; did I permanently kill the woman who Channels Blood Echoes into stat upgrades?

Tags: bloodborne

I was reading about NPC's that you can permanently kill - some you want to, some you might *not* want to. Included on that list was the woman in the Hunter's Dream.

Me and a friend have been playing together; and with the controller on its own on the sofa, the dog knocked it and hit the trigger and killed the Channel Blood Echoes woman :|

I didn't know whether she'd be dead forever - our current stats therefore locked in - so I pulled the power out of the PS4.

When I loaded the game back up, it said `Save data corrupted` and the `Continue` option had gone, leaving only `New game`.

Checking the PS+ Online Storage, I found a saved game from a few days ago, but I've now lost 12 hours of progress.... lol!

I'll replay it all, but I'm left wondering whether I pulled the power cord in vain, or not? :P

Comment: Funny, this is on Hot Network Questions...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your source of information is incorrect she can be killed but she ressurects when you reenter the Hunter's Dream.

So to answer your question, yes you pulled the plug in vain as currently there's no known way of permanently killing the doll.

Comment: lol kinda gutting but good to know, thanks

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. You may think of it as a bad dream :p

Comment: Since this happened, she disappeared again randomly. I teleported to a random tombstone (Central Yarnham) and teleported back to the Hunter's Dream and she re-appeared. Another time after, I noticed she was stood next to the grave stone next to the Insight Bath Messenger; even though it appeared that she'd disappeared.

Comment: Yeah she does this, she can spawn in her normal spot where you enter Hunter's dream or in front of the gravestone near the house. She can also sometimes be found sleeping, or saying a prayer.

Comment: This is interesting considering you could kill the Level Up characters in Demon Souls and Dark Souls 2. I guess this is an improvement though.

Comment: @Reafexus Killing the Maiden in Black in Demon's Souls can only be done after killing the final boss. If you try to kill her earlier, she apologizes that she "canst not die."